# Lodash group by undefined

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I have a Lodash list of animals that I'm attempting to group by Species. First I'm grabbing the JSON then applying the grouping and then feeding this in a for loop on an ionic list. Without the grouping, the data loads into the list but when applying the grouping I'm getting the data back as undefined.

```
 // Get the list of residents
 this.wwapi.getRepoData('discovery/find/' + this.section).subscribe(data => {
     this.allResidents = data;
     this.allResidentsAlphabet = _.chain(data).groupBy('Species').toPairs().map(item => _.zipObject(['SpeciesName', 'Species', item])).value();
     this.residents = this.allResidentsAlphabet;
});
```

The dummy JSON data is structured like this:

```
{"Profileid":0,
"Name":"Annie",
"Dateadded":null,
"Picture":"assets/img/mammals/hero/1.jpg",
"About":null,
"Habitat":null,
"Story":null,
"Sizegraphic":null,
"Discoveryid":"mammals",
"Age":null,
"Ageinwild":null,
"Food":null,
"Foodinwild":null,
"Avgheight":null,
"Avgweight":null,
"Species":"skunk",
"Height":null,
"Weight":null,
"Likes":null}]
```

I suspect the problem might be with the mapping as the return I get from a console log on the data is:

> Object Species : undefined SpeciesName : undefined skunk,[object
>   Object],[object Object] : undefined

So I can see it is returning them, but in a weird way?

Comment: what is that you are doing. Confusing as you are using `chain` and `zip` ! elaborate

Comment: I'm trying to group the animals by the species value so I can divide them by species in ionic

Comment: you need to add a condition if the data is completely retrieved or `length ===0`. Thats why your code breaks

Comment: Where does that need to added? and how would it change the code? Also the data does come back but just in the wrong place I think

Comment: inside your subscribe()

Comment: I don't think that's going to resolve the issue - the data variable returns the expected result - it's when you apply the lodash statement that it comes back undefined

Comment: put a break point and see how many times your subscription is triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a bit of a play with your mapping operation - I think the issue might be this call after looking at the Lodash docs:

```
// Item isn't a prop name here, and no values are specified
_.zipObject(['SpeciesName', 'Species', item])
```

If you use the following, I think you might get the data you're looking for:

```
_.chain(data)
    .groupBy('Species')
    .toPairs()
    .map(item => _.zipObject(['SpeciesName', 'Species'], item))
    .value();
```

Not sure if this is the data you're looking for as you didn't specify your output in the question - if it's not, please specify your desired output so we can help further.